# Primefaces datatable - sorting and filtering not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with dynamic header and columns based on the selected period and infomation to display. The problem is that I keep getting and exception while trying to either sort or filter data.

I am using Primefaces 5.0 and my datatable looks as follows:

```
<p:scrollPanel id="reportsScroll"  style= "#{reportsMB.gridSize}" >


<p:dataTable  id="reportsTable" var="rowData" value="#{reportsMB.gridData}" widgetVar="reportsTable"
    filteredValue="#{reportsMB.filteredValues}" paginator="true" rows="100"
    currentPageReportTemplate="Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of 
    {totalRecords} teams, Page: {currentPage}/{totalPages}"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}
    {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,25,50,100">


     <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel style="float:left">
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('reportsTable').filter()" style="width:150px;" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>

     <p:columnGroup type="header">

         <p:row>

             <c:forEach items="#{reportsMB.sumaryInfo}" var="sumary">
            <p:column rowspan="#{sumary.rows}" sortBy="#{rowData[sumary.key]}" rendered="#{sumary.name == 'User display name'}"
            filterStyle="display:none" styleClass="#{reportsMB.detailsSelected ? 'userHeaderSize' : ''}" filterBy="#{rowData[sumary.key]}"
            filterMatchMode="contains" headerText="#{sumary.name}" />

            <p:column rowspan="#{sumary.rows}" sortBy="#{rowData[sumary.key]}" rendered="#{sumary.name != 'User display name'}"
            filterStyle="display:none" styleClass="#{reportsMB.detailsSelected ? 'headerSize' : ''}" filterBy="#{rowData[sumary.key]}"
            filterMatchMode="contains" headerText="#{sumary.name}" />
            </c:forEach>

             <c:forEach items="#{reportsMB.months}" var="month">
            <p:column rendered="#{reportsMB.detailsSelected}" colspan="#{month.columns}" headerText="#{month.name}" />
            </c:forEach>

        </p:row>

          <p:row rendered="#{reportsMB.detailsSelected}">                
             <c:forEach items="#{reportsMB.weeks}" var="week">
            <p:column colspan="#{week.columns}"  headerText="#{week.name}" />
          </c:forEach>


        </p:row>


         <p:row rendered="#{reportsMB.detailsSelected}">

             <c:forEach items="#{reportsMB.daysNames}" var="dayName">
            <p:column headerText="#{dayName}"  />
            </c:forEach>

        </p:row>



        <p:row rendered="#{reportsMB.detailsSelected}">

             <c:forEach items="#{reportsMB.days}" var="day">
            <p:column headerText="#{day.name}" width="20"  sortBy="#{rowData[day.key]}" />
            </c:forEach>

        </p:row>



    </p:columnGroup>


    <p:columns value="#{reportsMB.sumaryInfo}"  var="sumary">

    <h:outputText value="#{rowData[sumary.key]}"> </h:outputText>

    </p:columns>


    <p:columns  rendered="#{reportsMB.detailsSelected}" value="#{reportsMB.days}"  var="day" id="idul">

    <h:outputText style="color:green;" rendered="#{rowData[day.key] == 'OH'}"  value="#{rowData[day.key]}"> </h:outputText>     

    <h:outputText style="color:#1cd5ed;" rendered="#{rowData[day.key] == 'REG' or rowData[day.key] == 'RES'}"  value="#{rowData[day.key]}"> </h:outputText>

    <h:outputText style="color:red;" rendered="#{rowData[day.key] == 'SICK'}" value="#{rowData[day.key]}"> </h:outputText>

    <h:outputText style="color:black;" rendered="#{rowData[day.key] == 'UNP'}"  value="#{rowData[day.key]}"> </h:outputText>

    <h:outputText style="color:#ff69b4;" rendered="#{rowData[day.key] == 'SPEC'}"  value="#{rowData[day.key]}"> </h:outputText>

    <h:outputText style="color:orange;" rendered="#{rowData[day.key] == 'OVRT'}"  value="#{rowData[day.key]}"> </h:outputText>

    <h:outputText style="color:gray;" rendered="#{rowData[day.key] == 'WE'}"  value="#{rowData[day.key]}"> </h:outputText>

    <h:outputText style="color:black;" rendered="#{rowData[day.key] == 'NH' or rowData[day.key] == 'GONE'}"  value="#{rowData[day.key]}"> </h:outputText>

    </p:columns>
```

The exception is :

```
May 30, 2014 11:13:27 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFO: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find column with key: datatable:reportsTable:j_idt99
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find column with key: datatable:reportsTable:j_idt99
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumn(DataTable.java:773)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.decode(SortFeature.java:87)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:61)
May 30, 2014 11:13:27 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
SEVERE: javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{rowData.null}
```

Can anyone tell me how to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line, `onkeyup="PF('reportsTable').filter()"` , is incorrect since  `reportsTable` is defined as an id. It should be defined as a widgetVar. So add `widgetVar="reportsTable"` will probably solve your problem.

Comment: it is defined as a widgetVar to. This was allowed in PF5 and did work in all browsers but IE

Answer (score 0):

Last time something similar happened to me, I had forgotten to enclose the dataTable with a form tag. It's a simple idea, but it took me some time trying to find the problem.